# Matching measured eigenvalue of a matrix

Tags: homework-and-exercises, eigenvalue, algorithms, matrix-model

Given a Matrix of the form below, we have 8 variables, $\omega_{i}$ and $J_{ij}$. we want to diagonalise the Matrix to obtain values to match the observed Eigenvalue in an Experiment. i.e. $\bar{\omega_{1}}$, $\bar{\omega_{2}}$, $\bar{\omega_{3}}$, $\bar{\omega_{4}}$ are the Eigenvalue of the diagonalised Matrix (the bottom matrix)
Question: How does vary the values of $J_{ij}$ and $\omega$ , where $i,j = 1,2,3,4.$ until the diagonalised Hamiltonian converges to $\bar{\omega_{1}}$=7, $\bar{\omega_{2}}$=8, $\bar{\omega_{3}}$=9, $\bar{\omega_{4}}$ = 10.

Hint: I tried to guess the Js values and $\omega $ values by setting all the $omega_{i}$ and $J_{ij}$ to be equal, and vary one at a time, it turns out to be immensely inefficient by guessing the J as the Problem consists of too many degrees of freedom.

\begin{pmatrix}\omega_1 &J_{12}& 0 & J_{14}\\ J_{12} & \omega_2 & J_{23} & 0\\ 0 & J_{23} &\omega_3 & J_{34}\\ J_{14} & 0 & J_{34} & \omega_4\end{pmatrix}

\begin{pmatrix}\bar{\omega_1} &0& 0 & 0\\0 & \bar{\omega_2} &0& 0\\ 0 &0&\bar{\omega_{3}} & 0\\0 & 0 & 0& \bar{\omega_{4}}\end{pmatrix}

The reason it might sound confusing, because this is a physics problem, nevertheless it amounts to simple diagonalisation of Hamiltonian if we have a good algorithm.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking here - what do you mean by "efficiently matching" "Experiment values"? What are the $\omega_i$ and the $J_{ij}$? What about the standard method of obtaining the eigenvalues (zeros of the characteristic polynomial) doesn't work here?

Comment: Also you can vote to reopen your own question.

Comment: @ACuriousMind This is actually a physics problem,. Where we have 4  LC resonators couple to each other. Each resonator interacts with each neighbouring with coupling strength Jij. And the question is what Jij and resonant frequency $\omega_{i}$ you need to fit the observed values in experiment... these values would correspond to the diagonlised hamiltonian eigenvalues

Comment: I think the question is clear. However the problem does not have a unique solution, because there are 8 unknowns and just 4 equations.

To see this explicitly, you could consider a simpler 2x2 problem, and suppose the J's are small enough that perturbation theory is valid.
You then have that $\bar{\omega_1} = \omega_1 + |J_{12}|^2/(\omega_1 - \omega_2)$ and $\bar{\omega_2} = \omega_2 + |J_{12}|^2/(\omega_2 - \omega_1)$.
These two equations aren't enough to determine the 3 unknowns. But if you specified, say, $J_{12}$, you could solve for the $\omega$'s.

Comment: For the full problem, you'd have to specify 4 of the unknowns (say the 4 $J_{ij}$'s) and use a numerical solver to find the $\omega$'s.

Comment: @PaulG Thanks ! It was later realised that actually i also have the amplitude of the eigenvector.. so there i get 4 more data points to solve this 8 unknowns